Plumbing way to do no-fast-forward merge
I'm working on a project that involves using git plumbing methods. I want to implement git no-fast-forward merge (aka three-way merge). I'm not sure which plumbing methods would be suitable for this case
I've already tried using:

git read-tree -m <branch1> <branch2>
and then
git merge-index git-merge-one-file -a

it looks promising, but what I got is:
<<<<<<< .merge_file_d4sCZV
This is main branch
=
This is branch 1
>>>>>>>.merge_file_gbJVvh

Of course, conflict looks as it should be, but conflict indicators are a bit strange (In term of merge_file_XXXXX, its not like <<< HEAD etc. Maybe should they be like this, when using lov-level approch?).
Is there a more "proper" way to do this using Git plumbing methods? Or is this how it should be?


Is it really > > > > > > > .merge_file_gbJVvh? And not >>>>>>> .merge_file_gbJVvh? 2) I find the examples in libgit2 to be helpful..


git merge-one-file is, as the git merge-index docs point out but (strangely) the git merge-one-file docs don't, pretty much a sample script, it's a wrapper around git merge-file which is the core command to do an actual three-way automerge and lets you (but git-merge-one-file doesn't) supply labels for the source files.
Hunt up the script in libexec/git-core, have your way with it.

Thanks! With git merge-file and some others commands (like checkout-index, ls-files, cat-file) i was able to make my own labels.
I will also look into libexec/git-core (haven't known about it, may be a wealth of knowledge for deep understanding of low-level git) - I think it will help me much.
